# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219 using Postman

Tags: php, laravel-5, postman

I've a simple `POST` route setup on my `routes.php` file and it pointed to a controller method called `authenticate`.

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/authenticate', 'TrackerAuthenticationController@authenticate');
});
```

TrackerAuthenticateController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TrackerAuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request) {
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

However, when I send a `POST` request using the Postman HTTP client it returned error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219`. It doesn't return the `success` message. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you also tried with form submitting through browser ? May be you are sending get request from postman ? can you show how you are sending through postman ?

Comment: I'm sending `POST` request from the Postman. I've also tried with form submitting and it works with the form submission. Here's the relevant screenshot from my end with Postman. https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7i7r3bdjegkc76/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-10%20at%202.37.31%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Post a copy of your POSTman Request.

Comment: show the headers from postman request

Comment: The Postman is getting `500 internal server error` and the `MethodNotAllowedException` from the Laravel. Here's the Postman headers screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4q7iinlqsb86ft/Screen%20Shot%202016-02-10%20at%202.54.35%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: @MdMazedulIslamKhan what about input headers?

Comment: What did you mean by input headers?

Comment: It looks like if I move the Route from Web Middleware to outside it works fine. However, then why don't within the Web Middleware. Is this for CSRF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was experiencing is caused by the CSRF token. Disabling the CSRF token from the `VerifyCsrfToken` class resolved this.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'authenticate'
    ];
}
```